# C signals do not work correctly

Tags: c, process, signals

I'm facing an error with the folllowing code.
It only executes the handler related to the odd numbers (in case the parent produces a odd random number included between 1 and 10), while the one for the even is always "mute".
Could someone help me out?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/msg.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <math.h>

pid_t pid1,pid2;
int r, ric1, ric2;
int fd[4];  //per 2 processi figli

void handler_one(){
    read(fd[0], &ric1, sizeof(int));
    printf("Im the first child process...the even received numebr is...%d\n", ric1);
    sleep(1);
}

void handler_two(){
    read(fd[2], &ric2, sizeof(int));
    printf("I'm the second child process...the odd receiver number is...%d\n", ric2);
    sleep(1);
}

void main(){


    pipe(fd);
    pipe(fd+2);

    pid1=fork();
    if(pid1)
        pid2=fork();

    while(1){
        if(pid1<0 || pid2<0){
            perror("AN ERROR OCCURRED!!!!!!!\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        else if(!pid1 && pid2){ //child #1
            signal(SIGUSR1, handler_one);
        }
        else if(pid1 && !pid2){ //child #2
            signal(SIGUSR2, handler_two);
        }
        else{   //padre
            printf("I'm the parent and I'm gonna send a random number\n");
            r=rand()%10+1;
            if(r%2==0){
                write(fd[1], &r, sizeof(int));
                kill(pid1, SIGUSR1);
            }               
            else{
                write(fd[3], &r, sizeof(int));
                kill(pid2, SIGUSR2);
            }
            sleep(1);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You never seed the random generator. So I would guess it is always producing the same number.

Comment: Before your while loop, try this:  `printf("I am PID %u.  pid1 is %u, pid2 is %u\n", getpid(), pid1, pid2);`  Then inspect your if/else if logic.

Comment: @pilcrow this is probably a better answer than mine, in that it actually teaches instead of just providing a solution.

Comment: **1)** `void handler_one(int signum){` (same for two) **2)** you should not use `printf()` in a signal handler **3)** `int main(void)`

Answer (score 3):

Your condition for setting up the child 1 signal handler is incorrect.  Instead of

```
   else if(!pid1 && pid2){ //child #1
```

it should be

```
   else if(!pid1 && !pid2){ //child #1
```

Not sure if you are guaranteed pid1 and pid2 are initialized to zero, you may want to do that explicitly.

Comment: Global and static variables are guaranteed to be initialized to 0, although it's a good idea to make it explicit when you depend on it.

Comment: In this case it does not work (as before). I want two create to childern directly related to the parent...but the problem is the part of the rand() and on the control on r...but I cannot understand why it does not check the condition  
`r=rand()%10+1;
            if(r%2==0)`